# Getting all elements (not children) between two elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a GridView control (ASP.NET) that contains a variable number of rows and sometimes another GridView.  There are "header" rows that are just spans with a specific CSS class, and under each "header" can be any number of `<tr>` rows or even additional tables.

The grid is separated into "header" cells and then regular cells (there are also subheaders but for my purposes they are regular cells).  What I need to be able to do is get a list of all the elements (I can filter it down later, starting with the basics now) between one header element and the next header element.

I've tried using the `nextUntil` method but it doesn't work properly and doesn't give me all of the elements between the two headers (it looks like it's only giving me the elements inside that particular row; there can be many tr rows in between each header row).

Here's a stripped-down HTML table illustrating the normal setup:

```
<table class="adminList">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="gvConcepts" rules="cols" cellspacing="0"
      cellpadding="3" border="1">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="permissionsList">
                <span id="lblConceptGroupName1" class="header">
                API</span>
                <input id="chkCanView1" type="checkbox">
                View</input>
                <input id="chkCanUpdate2" type="checkbox">
                Update</input>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="permissionsList">
                <span id="lblConceptGroupName2" class="header">
                Billing</span>
                <input type="checkbox">View</input>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="permissionsList">
                <span id="lblConceptGroupName3" class="header">
                Config</span>
                <span class="subheading">Accessorials</span>
                <input type="checkbox">View</input>
                <input type="checkbox">Add</input>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="permissionsList">
                <span class="subheading">App Settings</span>
                <input type="checkbox">View</input>
                <input type="checkbox">Update</input>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="permissionsList">
                <span class="subheading">Carrier</span>
                <input type="checkbox">View</input>
                <input type="checkbox">Add</input>
                <input type="checkbox">Update</input>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="permissionsList">
                <span id="lblConceptGroupName4" class="header">
                Email Configuration</span>
                <input type="checkbox">View</input>
                <input type="checkbox">Add</input>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="permissionsList">
                <span class="subheading">Email Message</span>
                <input type="checkbox">View</input>
                <input type="checkbox">Update</input>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, for example, the "Email Configuration" section has four checkboxes (two directly next to the header column `Email Configuration` and two in the subheading `Email Message`).  The `Config` area has seven (two each in Config, Accessorials, App Settings, and three in Carrier).

How would I go about doing this?  I am not sure if recreating the table in a better way is a viable option at this point but if that would be the easier way (I understand that might be the root of the problem since the HTML structure is wonky) I'll recommend it.

Comment: That's a mighty strange way of coding a table! jQuery `nextUntil` may be failing if the code isn't valid

Comment: Yes too much markup, but I like being thorough :)  @adam I agree, it's some weird GridView-within-a-GridView with a lot of it being dynamically created on the outer GridView's ItemDataBound.  There's a very good chance that's the issue but I need "proof" to suggest we recode it properly.  Also the "spans" are the ASP.NET label controls, for the record.

Comment: It shouldn't be a table - it's not tabular data. There's your proof! CSS floats are the future (of your problem).

Comment: Heh yeah, I agree.  I think a GridView was the fastest solution the other developers could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var headerArray = new Array();
    var trs = $('#gvConcepts').find('tr');
    var elemArray = null;

    trs.each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        if($this.find('span.header').length>0){//new element array
            if(elemArray != null){
                headerArray.push(elemArray);
            }
            elemArray = new Array();
            loadElementsFromRow(elemArray,$this);
        }else{
            if(elemArray != null){//don't start until header is found
                loadElementsFromRow(elemArray,$this);
            }
        }
    });
    if(elemArray != null){
        headerArray.push(elemArray);
    }
    test(headerArray);

});
function loadElementsFromRow(a, r){
    //r.find('*') to get every element
    r.find('input').each(function(){
        a.push($(this));
    });
}

function test(headerArray){
    console.log('headerArray.length: '+ headerArray.length);
    for(var i=0; i<headerArray.length; i++){
        console.log('######################### header index: '+ i);
        var elements = headerArray[i];
        console.log('elements.length: '+ elements.length);
        for(var j=0; j<elements.length; j++){
            var e = elements[j];
            console.log('Element: ' + e.attr('id'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check that.  I think that the idea will be scrapped rather than redo the GridView ("that" type of environment; doing it properly is never an option...) but I'll check your post out if I get the chance.